# JEditorKit color single chars without html

Tags: java, colors, jeditorpane

I want to mark parts of a jeditorpane content with a color, without using the html type content type. is there a way to accomplish this, maybe playing around with the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without using the html type content type

This means you have a plan text file and you should be using a JTextPane. Then you can use attributes to color the text.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText("Some text for the text pane.");
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

// Color existing text

doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 5, keyWord, false);

// Add some text

try
{
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nEnd of text", keyWord );
}
catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
```

Comment: Okay, it works thank you. But why did you pass 5 to setCharacterAttributes() ? What is the length (length of the change in javadoc) in this context?

Comment: and one more thing: if i write something before the inserted string, it also gets this attributes.. how could i avoid this? So that only the inserted string getes marked?

Comment: please, could you answer that things? i don't want to start new questions for them..

Comment: @T_01 `But why did you pass 5 to setCharacterAttributes() ?` - It was just a random number I choose. Read the API for more information and try different values to see what happens. I don't understand the second question. When you use the insertString(...) method only the String you insert gets the attributes. It does not affect the characters already in the text pane.

Comment: for example - i call insertString just like you posted, and pass "Something". Now i put the cursor behind "Something" and type "hello",  it gets white like expected. Now i remove "hello" (the cursor is behind "Something" again) and type something again, it gets red. why? Or if i go before "Something" and type something, it also gets red - but the old entire "Something" string stays red too..

Comment: @T_01, this is the way the text pane works. Normally, every character you type inherits attributes from the previous character. I guess when the previous character is a new line character it inherits the attributes from the next character in the document. This is the default functionality of JTextPane and I have no ideas how to change it.